# Application of Arzela-Ascoli Thrm where $(f'_n)$ is uniformly bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function, arzela-ascoli

We have:

- Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of differentiable functions on the interval $[0, 2]$
- Assume that $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to a function $f$ on $[0, 2]$
- Assume there exists positive real $M$ st $\forall n,$ $ \sup_{x\in[0,2]}\{|f'_n(x)|\}=M$

Prove that there is a strictly increasing sequence $(n_k)$ such that $(f_{n_k})$ converges uniformly on $[0,2]$.

I know that the Arzela-Ascoli theorem has the conclusion I want but to use it I need

1. $(f_n)$ to be uniformly bounded
2. $(f_n)$ to be uniformly equicontinuous

How would you fulfill those two conditions?

So following suggestions I have:

For 1:

Here we WTS $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, x \in [0,2] |f_n(x)| \leq Y$ for some Y.

Pick arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_0 \in [0,2]$ then since $f_n \to f$ pointwise, $(f_n(x_0))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded thus $\forall n' \in \mathbb{N} |f_{n'}(x_0)| \leq Y.$ Then since $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we see that $f_n(x_0) \leq Y$ as required.

Then for 2:

let $\epsilon >0,\delta = \epsilon/M$ then $\forall x,y \in [0,2]$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ where $|x-y| < \delta,$ apply MVT to see $|f_n(y) -f_n(x)| = |f'_n(c)(y-x)| \leq M|(y-x)| \leq \epsilon$ as required.

Also as a followup do the condition applied here mean limit $f$ of $f_n$ is continuous?

Comment: Use Mean value Theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the bound on the derivative to get a uniform Lipschitz constant, which is more than enough for uniform equicontinuity; this follows from the mean value theorem or (if you prefer overkill) the fundamental theorem of calculus.

For the uniform bound, recall that a sequence of numbers that converges is bounded, so use that to get a bound on, say, $f_n(0)$. Then apply the uniform Lipschitz constant to propagate that bound across $[0,2]$.

Comment: I updated my question with my try. Could you check?

Comment: @CHTM The first part is not right; you can say that $f_n(x_0)$ is bounded but because there are infinitely many possible $x$ this is not enough to conclude that $|f_n(x)|$ has a universal bound for all $n$ and $x$, since a  priori the bound that you get for $|f_n(x_0)|$ could depend on $x_0$. The second part is right.

Comment: Hmm. I'm a little lost. Could you update your answer to include a proof for the uniform bound portion then? I might be able to better understand.

Comment: After some more thinking. Does something like this work? First you pick an $x \in [0,2]$ (say $x=0$) then since $f_n \to f$ pointwise there is a bound $Y_0$ for $(f_n(0))_{n=1}^{\infty}.$ Then you repeat this process for all $x \in [0,2]$. This gives you a set of bounds $\{Y_0, Y_{0.1}, Y_1, Y_{1.5}, ...\}$ then you take max of those bounds. This this new bound would be the $Y$ we want.

Comment: @CHTM That does ultimately work, but as a proof it does not, because you have no guarantee that that sup is finite. What I am suggesting is to say $|f_n(0)| \leq M_1$ and then use the Lipschitz constant to infer that $|f_n(x)| \leq |f_n(0)| + M|x| \leq M_1 + 2M$.

Comment: How about this:

Since $f_n$ converges pointwise, $(f_n(0))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded by say $T.$ That is $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} |f_n(0)| \leq T.$ Then pick any $n \in \mathbb{N}, x \in [0,2]$ then $|f_n(x)| = |f_n(x) - f_n(0) + f_n(0)| \leq |f_n(x) - f_n(0)| + |f_n(0)| \leq $ (apply MVT) $|f'_n(c)x| + T \leq Mx +T \leq 2M +T.$

Comment: @CHTM That's right.